# Using the Alaska Airlines Companion Fare on Air France

Tags: travel-companions, alaska-airlines

I have the Alaska Airlines MBNA Master Card. This card offers a [companion fare](http://www.rewardscanada.ca/alaska-mastercard-review.html) of 99$ + taxes. I wish to book a round trip ticket between Los Angeles and Tahiti on a partner airline like Air France.

Can I book myself a full fare ticket and pay 99$ + taxes for my companion?

I ask because using a companion fare is different from redeeming miles and I cannot find the fine print to see if the companion fare is only for Alaska Airlines or for partner airlines also.

Comment: No. It's Alaskan airlines only.

Answer (score 2):

For US based customers with an Alaska Airline affiliated card, the companion fare is limited to Alaska Airline flights only.  Your link indicated that maybe you are a Canadian card holder, but I would imagine the same rules would apply.

But realistically, expecting a $99 companion fare on an international flight to Tahiti would be dreaming.

http://www.alaskaair.com/content/mileage-plan/frequently-asked-questions/faq-companion-discount-code.aspx?lid=nav:mileagePlan-faq-companion

Comment: It's not that crazy to ask.  It's definitely good on Alaska's international flights, they just don't go to Tahiti.  (And Alaska flies some pretty expensive domestic routes; LAX => Dutch Harbor is more expensive than getting to Tahiti.)